# Is it better to have individual try...except in different parts of the code or a single at the start and end of the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

So, I was playing with `try...except`, and couldnt understand a few parts.
So, say there is a method:

```
def func():
    code a
    code b
```

Now, If I have to capture two exceptions in `code a` and `code b`.
One way could be as below:

```
def func():
    try:
        code a
    except Exception1:
        print("Except1")
    try:
        code b
    except Exception2:
        print("Except2")
```

Or, is it better to have it towards the start and end as shown?

```
def func():
    try:
        code a
        code b
    except Exception1:
        print("Except1")
    except Exception2:
        print("Except2")
```

Comment: It really depends on how you recover from the exceptions. if *code a*  fails, can you recover enough to still run *code b* ? if yes then you need separate blocks. as a rule of thumb i would go with separate blocks in most cases

Comment: like @Nullman says it depends what you do in these exceptions. Are the actions from code a a dependancy for code b? Can code b run regardless if code a worked or not? If code b relies on something from code a then put them in the same try block so when code a fails code b never runs. If code b should run regardless if code a works or not then put them in seperate try blocks.